# should FIPS self test be done for each application?

Tags: linux, openssl, fips

I have few applications making use of openssl crypto library. When i need to implement the power-on-self test for the crypto - as per FIPS 140-2 -

1) Should that be done only once when the system powers up ? (OR)
2) When each application starts using the crypto library ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working in US Federal?

Comment: What he said. Unless you are writing an application for the US government, *and* your project sponsor has specifically indicated that FIPS compliance is a requirement, you should ignore FIPS mode. It *decreases* overall security by disabling a number of modern cryptographic primitives which aren't part of the FIPS standard.

Comment: Thank  you very much for the response !

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OpenSSL FIPS Object Module 2.0 User Guide](https://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), the power-on self test runs automatically when `FIPS_mode_set()` is called. If you require FIPS 140-2 compliance for all your OpenSSL operations, then you must call that function before doing anything else in OpenSSL.

If you haven't already done so, you really need to read through the [OpenSSL FIPS 140 FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fipsnotes.html), which contains important information about what it means for an application to be FIPS-compliant. It also contains links to the FIPS user guides and security policies.

**It is impossible to be FIPS-compliant without following the instructions in these documents.**

Comment: Thank you very much luaphacim for the response and links !